# Setting the class of a div based on the contents of a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is probably pretty simple but I can't figure it out! I need to parse the text inside an  tag and set the class of a div based on it's contents. Here's what I need to do:

```
<div id="targetDiv">  Content Here  </div>
<a href="/BookingRetrieve.aspx?ID=6463">Open House - October 21, 2010</a>
<a href="/BookingRetrieve.aspx?ID=6463">Meeting - October 21, 2010</a>
```

I need to set the class of the first div to either "OpenHouse" or "Meeting" based on the contents of the text string inside the  tag. (Note: only one would be showing. I'm including both only for reference).

So if this were showing on the page:

```
<a class="linkText" href="/BookingRetrieve.aspx?ID=6463">Open House - October 21, 2010</a>
```

The div would be

```
<div id="targetDiv" class="OpenHouse">  Content Here  </div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
if($(".linkText").val().indexOf("House") == 0){$('#targetDiv').addClass('OpenHouse');};
```

For some reason this does not work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) you need [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like this:

```
if($(".linkText").text().indexOf("House") == 0){$('#targetDiv').addClass('OpenHouse');}
```

but that's a starts-with check, if you want a contains do `>= 0` like this:

```
if($(".linkText").text().indexOf("House") >= 0){$('#targetDiv').addClass('OpenHouse');}
```

Or just use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), like this:

```
if($(".linkText:contains('House')").length){$('#targetDiv').addClass('OpenHouse');}
```

Or if like your example the `<div>` is *just* before the `<a>`, you can do this:

```
$(".linkText:contains('House')").prev().addClass('OpenHouse');
$(".linkText:contains('Meeting')").prev().addClass('Meeting');
```

Comment: In your last example, I think you want `.length > 0`.  ;-)

Comment: @Nick — When I wrote that comment, it still said `.length >= 0`, which *isn't* quite the same.  :-)

Comment: @Ben - It *was* `> 0` for a moment, you would never use `>= 0` for `.length`, not in any case I can think of anyway...

Comment: @Nick — Precisely my point.  It looked like it had been copy/pasted from the second example and I didn't know you were still editing the answer, so didn't want it to slip by.